# Jupyter notebook Kernel keeps crashing when I try to run hugging face model

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am trying to do sentiment analysis on customer feedback. This is the code that I am using

```
import warnings
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.special import softmax
from transformers import logging
logging.set_verbosity_error()

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['This movie is great!', 'I watched insidious', 'Happy this movie!', 'I feel bored.', 'The weather is nice.', np.nan]})

def predict_sentiment(text):
    if pd.isna(text):
        return 'N/A' 
    MODEL = "cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL)
    model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
    encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_input)
    scores = output.logits[0].detach().numpy()
    scores = softmax(scores)
    ranking = np.argsort(scores)
    ranking = ranking[::-1]
    highest_sentiment = config.id2label[ranking[0]]
    return highest_sentiment

predicted_sentiments = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    text = row['text']
    sentiment = predict_sentiment(text)
    predicted_sentiments.append(sentiment)

df['Hugging Face'] = predicted_sentiments
df
```

it works and is giving really good results. We tested it for a sample of 20 feedbacks and it worked good. Now when I try to run this on the original dataset which has around only 200 feedback approx, the kernel keeps dying. Not sure what is going on, the dataset is really small and the kernel crashes within 1 minute of running the code. what could be the possible reasons of kernel crashing and how can I fix that?

Comment: Separate it from Jupyter by putting it in a script `.py` and try running as a traditional Python script from the command line in that environment  with`python myscript.py`. Others who know the ML field can probably point to this question being covered a lot already in this forum, unless your issue is somehow special. At this point that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Wayne it says zsh: segmentation fault  python file.py. from what I have read it indicates reaching memory out of bound but I am not sure why , the dataset is only 200 rows?

Comment: Yes, what you are seeing is the classic symptom of memory issue in Jupyter. I was hoping though since you say it isn't that large that removing the overhead of Jupyter was going to get you where you need to be. Sadly, it appears not. So another thing to look into is if are you actually sure your data is clean and you aren't hitting on some problematic data? Could it literally be a one or a few of your rows that is causing the problem? Like you are asking it to calculate infinity inadvertently? Can you repeat your first 20 rows 10 times? Plus how large are rows? You only state one dimension.

Comment: Sometimes it even crashes on the 20 rows so could be the model issue? I tried running it on Python's NLTK library and it's running. The issue is hugging face is giving better results but it keeps on crashing. Some sentences are around 62 words , 366 characters